# Is it possible to define host aliases in ansible, similar to ssh config?

Tags: ansible

In SSH config, you can use the following format to list multiple aliases that all specify the same host:

```
Host DEV-USA-BGW100 dev-usa-bgw100 USA100 usa100
    HostName 192.168.1.100
    User ansible

Host DEV-CAN-BGW101 dev-can-bgw101 CAN101 can101
    HostName 192.168.2.101
    User ansible

Host DEV-CAN-BGW102 dev-can-bgw102 CAN102 can102
    HostName 192.168.2.102
    User ansible
```

I would like to be able to do the same thing in **ansible**, but I'm unsure if it's possible.  The reason is I sometimes want to test a single command on a single host without typing the entire proper hostname verbatim.

I've been searching around but haven't been able to find an answer.  I did find a page that says that by default, **ansible** will use OpenSSH on the server, and thus should read the SSH config file.  I tested this, but it didn't work.

Comment: I had  asked the same question in  #ansible on freenode a while back. The answer was no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an inventory file or script that returns fully qualified host names. Then [use patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html).

```
ansible '*can*101*' -m ping
```

Or, you can have [groups of groups in inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables) deep enough where the group name is an alias for 1 or 2 devices.

Defining the same host by different names in inventory may result in tasks being done twice to the same device.

SSH config is a separate name resolution thing Ansible is not aware of.

Comment: I totally forgot about patterns, which will be useful.  I decided to take the time to try to create a bunch of nested groups to be able to account for the majority of these aliases.  Thanks!